# Finding the supremum of certain sets by taking derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, maxima-minima

How can I find the supremum of $\frac{nt}{1+nt} - \frac{mt}{1+mt}$, where $n$ and $m$ are any natural numbers and ${t}\in{[0,1]}$?

In particular, can I consider this as a maximization problem $max_{{t}\in{[0,1]}}\frac{nt}{1+nt} - \frac{mt}{1+mt}$, meaning that I can take the derivative with respect to $t$, equate it to zero and plug the value of the resulting value of $t$ into the expression that I maximize? I remember that one of my instructors used this kind of technique to find the supremum of a certain set, but I do not know in which sets we can use maximization, and I want to know the logic behind this process if it is valid.

Comment: Should work. Just make sure the t value you get is within that range and is a maximum. If there is no maximum in that range, check the endpoints (0,1)

Comment: Also I am assuming u mean an interval between the two expressions is ur set

Comment: I got it. Also, if $t$ was also a natural number, would it be okay to proceed similarly (maximizing in terms of t) and then find the maximum (natural) value of t that is closest to the value that I found by maximizing process?